# Print all of element inside Bracket json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I want to get all **'name'** from this json and **separate by comma**

```json
{
    "example": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "blah"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "nah"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "krah",
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "ugh"
        }
    ],
}
```

when im trying to:

```py
example = r_json['example']['name']
print(example)
```

it returns me:

```
    example = r_json['example']['name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

output i want is something like:

blah, nah, krah, ugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `"example"` is a list. To access items you need to use an index. e.g.

```
>>> r_json["example"][0]["name"]
'blah'
```

If you want to get all of the names, you need to loop through each item in the list.

```
>>> for i in range(len(r_json["example"])):
...    print(r_json["example"][i]["name"])
blah
nah
krah
ugh
```

A simpler way to do this would be to directly iterate over the list and not use an index:

```
>>> for example in r_json["example"]:
...    print(example["name"])
blah
nah
krah
ugh
```

To put them in a list you can do:

```
>>> names = []
>>> for example in r_json["example"]:
...    names.append(example["name"])
>>> names
['blah', 'nah', 'krah', 'ugh']
```

An even easier way is to use a comprehension:

```
>>> names = [example["name"] for example in r_json["example"]]
>>> names
['blah', 'nah', 'krah', 'ugh']
```

Once you have the `names` you can use str.join to make your final result:

```
>>> ", ".join(names)
'blah, nah, krah, ugh'
```

---

As a one liner just for fun:

```
>>> ", ".join(example["name"] for example in r_json["example"])
```

An even more fun one-liner!

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> ", ".join(map(itemgetter("name"), r_json["example"]))
'blah, nah, krah, ugh'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error says, the value under `r_json['example']` is a list of dictionaries, so you can't access it like: `r_json['example']['name']`. One way to get the names is to use a list comprehension:

```
example = [d['name'] for d in r_json['example']]
print(*example)
```

Output:

```
blah nah krah ugh
```